# Why is there a error in writing a new file in Python?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape a webpage and write the data in a txt.file.
Its throwing an error.

```
UnicodeEncodeError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_10484/2570620311.py in <module>
      5 
      6 with open(f'{title}.txt', 'w')as file:
----> 7     file.write(transcript)
      8 
      9 #print(title)

~\anaconda3\lib\encodings\cp1252.py in encode(self, input, final)
     17 class IncrementalEncoder(codecs.IncrementalEncoder):
     18     def encode(self, input, final=False):
---> 19         return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
     20 
     21 class IncrementalDecoder(codecs.IncrementalDecoder):

UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\ufb02' in position 32153: character maps to <undefined>
```

Code:

```
 import requests
 from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

 website="https://subslikescript.com/movie/Titanic-120338"
 result=requests.get(website)
 content=result.text

 soup=BeautifulSoup(content,'lxml')
 print(soup.prettify())

 box = soup.find('article',class_='main-article')

title=box.find('h1').get_text()
transcript=box.find('div',class_='full-script').get_text(strip=True,separator=' ')

with open(f'{title}.txt', 'w')as file:
file.write(transcript)
```

Comment: Try using `with open(YOUR_FILE, "w", encoding="utf-8") as file`.

Comment: Right.  To explain, on Windows, your file gets opened with an 8-bit encoding matching your current code page.  The default code pages don't include U+FB02, which is the "fl" ligature.  You need to pick another encoding.

Answer (score -1):

The error you're encountering, UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character, suggests that there is an issue with encoding when writing to the text file. This is often due to attempting to write Unicode characters that are not supported by the default encoding on your system.

You can try opening the file with a specific encoding when writing. UTF-8 is a common encoding for handling Unicode characters. Here's how you can modify your code:

```
    import requests
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

    website = "https://subslikescript.com/movie/Titanic-120338"
    result = requests.get(website)
    content = result.text

    soup = BeautifulSoup(content, 'lxml')
    print(soup.prettify())

    box = soup.find('article', class_='main-article')

    title = box.find('h1').get_text()
    transcript = box.find('div', class_='full-script').get_text(strip=True, 
    separator=' ')

    with open(f'{title}.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as file:
        file.write(transcript)
```

By specifying encoding='utf-8' when opening the file, you should be able to handle Unicode characters without encountering the encoding error.

I hope this is helpful, Happy learning.